# Powershell: how can I retrieve a list of memory usage by iexplore.exe URL

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, url, memory

For each Iexplore.exe process I need to retrieve the following using powershell;

```
URL                            Memory Usage(K)
http://www.google.com          80796
http://www.yahoo.com           34748
```

I only open 1 URL per Iexplore.exe process (no tabs).

`get-process iexplore` gives me good view of memory usage per process id.
For example;

```
PS> get-process iexplore

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------
    870      87    80796      15900   429    27.10   1720 iexplore
    850      82    34748      28548 -1781    23.04   3640 iexplore
```

and this snippet gives me the URLs that are open

```
PS> $urls = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()
PS> $urls | where-object { $_.name -eq "Internet Explorer"} | ForEach-Object {$_.LocationUrl, $_.name} 

https://some url .com
Internet Explorer
https://some url .com
Internet Explorer
```

But I dont know how to combine these concepts if at all possible. 
Alternatively anything that can give me the required output will suffice.

Reason:

We run several business objects dashboard as .SWF files in IE browsers, and a few other web page based dashboards.  then the video output of the server they run on are connected to various large format 1920x1080 displays.

Over time we get memory leak in IE.

This would allow us to monitor / log the memory usage over time of each Iexplore.exe process, and know which URL that process is accessing.

Many thanks in advance.

Sorry if the formatting of this post is crappy.  Its my first time!

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the process using the `MainWindowHandle`:

```
$ieInstances = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).Windows()  | where-object { $_.name -eq "Internet Explorer"}
$ieInstances | select LocationUrl, @{e={(Get-Process -Name iexplore| Where-Object MainWindowHandle -eq $_.HWND | select -expand PM)}; l="Memory Usage(K)"}
```